# Reproducing Gauss' famous proof

Tags: math-mode, align

The following appears in a text (in the context of generalizing Gauss' famous proof):
[image]

I would like to reproduce this, but I cannot figure out how to get the alignment down. I thought of trying to use `alignat` but that does not seem to help (or maybe I simply do not know how to use it properly). Also, I would like for the horizontal line to be placed properly, but this is what I have come up with so far which is rather poor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
S_n &=& a &+& (a+d) &+\cdots+& [a+(n-1)d]\\
S_n &=& [a+(n-1)d] &+& [a+(n-2)d] &+\cdots+& a\\\hline
2S_n &=& [2a+(n-1)d]&+& [2a+(n-1)d &+\cdots+&[2a+(n-1)d]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which gives
[image]

Any ideas on how to obtain the first image effectively?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're better using an `array` (with some tricks):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r *{5}{ >{{}}c<{{}} c } }
 S_n &=& a           &+& (a+d)      &+& \cdots &+& [a+(n-1)d]\\
\addlinespace
 S_n &=& [a+(n-1)d]  &+& [a+(n-2)d] &+& \cdots &+& a\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\addlinespace
2S_n &=& [2a+(n-1)d] &+& [2a+(n-1)d &+& \cdots &+& [2a+(n-1)d]
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `>{{}}c<{{}}` columns ensure correct spacing around the equals and plus signs, together with `\arraycolsep` set to zero.